# My userstyle - How do you think I should improve it ?

Tags: discussion, design

I got sick of looking at SE sites that are black on white - Us terminal users like dark themes, so I've gone all out to make a great userstyle, try it! - If you like it, improve it then tell us about it!

```
@namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);

@-moz-document domain("unix.stackexchange.com") {
.question-summary + .tagged-ignored {
    display: none !important;
}
body {
color: white !important;
background: black !important;
}
#h-unanswered-questions, .youarehere, .user-details a, .bottom-notice a, a#h-meta, a#h-chat-link {
color: SpringGreen !important;
}
#tabs a, #hlinks-custom a, .comment-user, .relativetime {
color: LightGreen !important;
}
#wmd-button-bar {
background-color: SlateGrey !important;
}
a.question-hyperlink {
color: #0087FF !important;
}
.vote-count-post {
color: white !important;
text-shadow: 2px 2px 0 SlateGrey !important;
}
pre, code, input, textarea#wmd-input.processed, .tagged-interesting {
background-color: #2F2F2F !important;
color: white !important;
}
.status strong {
color: LightGreen !important;
}
.unanswered {
color: LightGreen !important;
}
a.post-tag {
background-color: #2F2F2F !important;
color: SlateGrey !important;
}
.answered {
color: LightGrey !important;
}
#system-message a {
color: orange !important;
}
.answered strong {
color: LightGrey !important;
}
#footer-menu a, #copyright, #additional-notices, #questions-count p, #hlinks-user a, .module h4, .item-multiplier, .comment-date, .comment-copy, .bottom-notice, .label-key {
color: white !important;
}
.comment-hover {
background-color: #2F2F2F !important;
}

#copyright a {
color: orange !important;
}
#copyright a:hover, .label-value {
color: LightGoldenRodYellow !important;
}
#svnrev, .reputation-score, .badgecount  {
color: white !important;
}
}
```

Comment: [Physics](http://physics.stackexchange.com/) just got a dark theme, and there was considerable complaining :)

Comment: I like the new physics style - maybe SE sites should think about allowing the user to select which style with a theme switcher.

Comment: That would be awesome! There's a [minimalist style](http://stackapps.com/questions/2143/minimaloverflow-a-themescript-for-stackexchange) being worked on now that works cross-site, and could probably be expanded into a magic multi-theme script

Comment: ++ switcher with a few optional themes, and a default.

Answer (score 2):

This is nice!

Can it be generalized to work on any Stack Exchange site, and put on

https://stackapps.com/?tab=scripts

at all?

Comment: Sure, I'll do some more work on it and post it, glad you like it!

Comment: Maybe I can step in and help. Would a SE-wide theme manager make a good UserScript?